# How to remove the elevation (shadow) in a SearchDelegate?

Tags: flutter

I want to remove the shadow from the search bar when using `SearchDelegate` but I can't find how to. Any tips?

[image: Screenshot]

This is basically all the code:

```
showSearch(
  context: context,
  delegate: CustomSearchDelegate(),
);
```

CustomSearchDelegate() just contains an empty search delegate widget/class.

Comment: could you post your current code and small screenshot?

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add this inside the Searchdelegate class:**

```
 @override
  ThemeData appBarTheme(BuildContext context){
    assert(context != null);
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    assert(theme != null);
    return theme.copyWith(
      primaryColor: Colors.grey[50],

    );
  }
```

and this to the main app theme:

```
MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(elevation: 0.0), //This is important
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
```

Make changes accordingly in your `ThemeData()`  and add the `appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(elevation: 0.0),` to remove the elevation and the SearchDelegate theme as it is your search delegate class which will ensure that the elevation defined in the ThemeData of your material app is implemented.

***Note: I guess, that the elevation set in the ThemeData will affect the elevation of the appbar in other pages all over the app too.***

**Result:**
[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcIdk.jpg)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this did the trick! It didn't change the appbar elevation in my other pages, so that's also good!

Answer (score 5):

```
@override
  ThemeData appBarTheme(BuildContext context) {
    return super.appBarTheme(context).copyWith(
      appBarTheme: super.appBarTheme(context).appBarTheme.copyWith(
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
    );
  }
```